# Can I filter mac addresses within DNS?

Tags: dns, vnc-server, debian-buster

is it possible to setup dns in such a way that only predefined mac addresses are allowed access? Thus meaning only my laptop and cellphone will be able to login?

The service and system to which the dns points is VNC on debian linux.
My router through which the port is forwarded is a D-link router.

Comment: You can put filters on IP addresses, but not MAC addresses, because those are local to a LAN where the DNS uses IP and is global. Also even if that was possible, MAC spoofing is easy (clients can change their MAC address)

Comment: Thank you, I ended up just limiting the user's capabilities when accessing through VNC